# Python webrowser open url with bookmarks like www.something.com/file.html#top

Tags: python, html, browser

I am using a hmtl file as a help document for my program, and would really like to be able to open the file at a specific point. i assumed i would be able to do this using the built in webbrowser module by specifying a url with a bookmark.

this is my html file name: help.html
i assumed that i would be able to use: help.html#top

this is the code i am using to open the file, this works fine:

```
webbrowser.open("Files\help.html")
```

and this is the code i have been trying to use to open at a specific point which ie9 apparently cant display (not sure why it is trying to load in ie9 as chrome is my default browser, and the working one above loads in chrome):

```
webbrowser.open("Files\help.html#2.1.0")
```

any ideas guys?

Comment: Are you sure there is an existing anchor in the file by the name "2.1.0"? If not, you would add one like this: `<a name="2.1.0" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`webbrowser.open()` calls the browser from the command line. So you might try to do that yourself first. If that doesn't work, it's likely that your browser just doesn't support that for local files or something.

With Ubuntu+Firefox for example, `webbrowser.open()` does what you ask. (but - as Dave Webb said in his answer - you do have to provide a `file:` url, not just a filename).
(not on Windows at the moment, so haven't checked there)

As for why it doesn't load chrome but ie9: (you can look in the webbrowser.py code yourself if you  want) I think it does try to use your default webbrowser, by doing `os.startfile(url)`. What happens when you doubleclick your help.html file, of when you just type `help.html` (adjust path as needed) at the command line? It should do the same.

EDIT:

It seems that it doesn't always use the command line. On Windows, when trying to use the default browser, it uses `os.startfile()` which in turn uses the win32 `ShellExecute` api. `ShellExecute` can be used to perform certain actions on a file, folder or URL, like "open", "edit" or "print" with its default application. In this case, `ShellExecute` is asked to "open" the URL.

It seems however, that `ShellExecute` ignores the fragment identifier (the part after `#`) when opening `file:` urls. Strangely enough, this is not the case with `http:`urls. Presumably, a `file:` url is just converted to a plain filename first.

There seems to be little you can do about this except:

- write something that "does the right thing" yourself (and register it as a browser controller for the `webbrowser`module, and use `webbrowser.get()` to get your controller, see [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get))
- as many applications do: configure the browser you want to use (or make it possible for your users to do so). The easiest way would be to set the `BROWSER` environment variable (see [webbrowser module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html))
- serve the file via a localhost http server, and open the http url, which would then be something like "http://. "http://localhost:8000/help.html#2.1.0". (The [SimpleHttpServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html) module might come in handy)

Or, the easiest way: as you seem to be on windows: just try to open internet explorer specifically:

```
  try:
      browser = webbrowser.get('c:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IEXPLORE.EXE')
  except Webbrowser.Error:
      browser = webbrowser.get()
  browser.open(url)
```

(This will fall back to using the default, so your code would still work on other platforms)

Comment: Let it be known that i am not good with command line, so don't know where to begin with opening a html file from there. I tried providing a full file: url but that didn't work either (file opened but bookmark was ignored). double clicking html file opens it in chrome. Now i know webbrowser calls it from the command line i can redirect my search, so thank you! i will post on here if i find anything!

Comment: ok so it appears that it can't be done from command line, so i assume it cant be done with webbrowser. Do you know of any other methods that may allow me to do this?

Comment: If the browser is being called from the command line (a true shell?) could the # sign be interpreted as a comment delimiter?

Comment: that would explain why it appears to be totally ignored, but i have no idea how to get around this

Comment: @Ben: Updated my answer with about all I could come up with. (Sorry it took so long ;-))

Comment: @Steven, thanks steven, the easiest/last solution worked like a dream!

Answer (score 1):

I think `webbrowser` is expecting a URL, so have you tried something like:

```
webbrowser.open("file://c:/path/to/files/html.html#2.1.0")
```

Comment: alas, while that does open the file, it seems to forget about the #2.1.0 part and just loads up help.html

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77865371/12690376), this works for me:

```py
import sys
import subprocess

html_filepath = r'c:/path/to/files/html.html#2.1.0'

subprocess.check_call(
    [sys.executable, '-m', 'webbrowser', html_filepath]
)
```

As you can see you do not need to prepend `file://`.