# Python Webbrowser anchors on Local html file

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

When trying to to use '#' to specify anchor point in a webpage using the webbrowser lib, it seem to only work on websites, and not on local html files
`webbrowser.open(https://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open)` works, but
`webbrowser.open(file://C:\path\to\webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open)` does not.

Is there something I am missing to be able to do it, or is it simply not supported?
If so, are there any alternatives?

I need the html page to be available offline

Comment: That's not the same thing.

Comment: @PeterWood Not certain what you mean?
If I open the file `file://C:\path\to\webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open` in my browser it jump correctly to the headline. However, doing so using the webbrowser lib it does not

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I would like to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why but this works:

```py
import sys
import subprocess

html_filepath = r'C:\path\to\webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open'

subprocess.check_call(
    [sys.executable, '-m', 'webbrowser', html_filepath]
)
```

This is equivalent to running the following command in the terminal:

```
python -m webbrowser "C:\path\to\webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open"`
```

It's explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#module-webbrowser). You can also add the argument `-n` to open a new browser window or `-t` to open a new tab.

As you can see you do not need to prepend `file://`.

Answer (score -1):

Just do this -

```
webbrowser.open_new(C:/path/to/webbrowser.html)
```

This will open html file offline

Comment: This does not quite anwser my question. I am able to open the file, but not at the correct anchor point `#webbrowser.open`